# Do-while Loop Conditional Statement Negation Equivalence

Tags: c++, logic, conditional-statements, negation

New to the community and programming. I was curious as to why these two logical statements are equivalent in my program. I can't seem to wrap my head around this specific logic at the moment, and I wanted to understand why it works this way.

Initially, I had written the following:

```
    char c;
    do {
        cin >> c;
        cout << "You entered: " << c << "\n";
    } while (c != 'Y' || c != 'y' || c != 'N' || c || 'n');
    return 0;
}
```

However, this does not seem to work unless I use &&.
Later, I found out that using or does work, but my negation must be on the outside. These are the two conditionals that confuse me. Why are they logically equivalent?

```
while (!(c == 'Y' || c == 'y' || c == 'N' || c || 'n')); // Will run until c is the following
while (c !='Y' && c != 'y' && c != 'N' && c != 'n'); // Will also run but without being negated.
```

Comment: De Morgan's Theorem might be a useful search term for you here

Answer (score 0):

These logical expressions in the do-while loops

```
while (!(c == 'Y' || c == 'y' || c == 'N' || c || 'n')); // Will run until c is the following
while (c == 'Y' && c == 'y' && c == 'N' && c == 'n'); // Will also run but without being negated.
```

are not equivalent.

The expression

```
while (!(c == 'Y' || c == 'y' || c == 'N' || c || 'n'));
```

is equivalent to

```
while ( c != 'Y' && c != 'y' && c != 'N' && !c && !'n' );
```

if you have an expression like for example

```
a == b || c == d
```

then its negation

```
!( a == b || c == d )
```

is equivalent to

```
!( a == b ) && !( c == d )
```

and at last to

```
a != b && c != d
```

Pay attention to that this do-while loop

```
char c;
do {
    cin >> c;
    cout << "You entered: " << c << "\n";
} while (c != 'Y' || c != 'y' || c != 'N' || c || 'n');
```

does not make sense. For example if the user entered `'N'` nevertheless the loop continues its iteration because the first subexpression `c != 'Y'` evalautes to true.

Comment: Wow that was incredibly fast. I was re-editing the question posted when I realized I accidentally wrote "==" for the && conditional statement and had to correct it. I do understand they are considered equivalent, but why?